# EntityDataSource does not remember the "Where" property at callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I have a EntityDataSource that has ViewState enabled. If the user pushes the Filter button then I set the "Where" property of the EntityDataSource and I add a WhereParameter.

When I make a callback then the "Where" property is null, but the WhereParameter is still remembered. I want EntityDataSource to remember the "Where" property too. How can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="dsOutgoingShipment" EntitySetName="OutgoingShipment" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="DAL.IngramEKAER_Entities" EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True">
</asp:EntityDataSource>

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dsOutgoingShipment.WhereParameters.Add("Line", System.Data.DbType.String, tbLine.Text);
        dsOutgoingShipment.Where = "it.line=@Line";
    }
```

Comment: You should only set `WhereParameter` with `AutoGenerateWhereClause` enabled.

Comment: @GertArnold: In this example they use WhereParameters without AutoGenerateWhereClause: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.whereparameters(v=vs.110).aspx